# API Call Fails on Swift Uikit

Tags: swift, rest, networking, uikit

This is my function to make API call:

```
func fetchSimilarRecipes(recipeID: String) {
        print("Fetching similar recipes for recipeID: \(recipeID)")
        NetworkManager.shared.getRecipesInfo(for: .getSimilarRecipes(recipeID), completed: { _ in }, getSimilarCompleted:  { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let similarRecipes):
                print("Fetched similar recipes: \(similarRecipes)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.similarRecipesArray = similarRecipes
                    print("SIMILAR RECIPES ARE: \(self.similarRecipesArray)")
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching similar recipes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
            }
        })
```

when I put a breakpoint at the first line in this function it is triggered. And I get `print("Fetching similar recipes for recipeID: \(recipeID)")` printed in the console. However, the endpoint named `GetsimilarRecipes` inside my network manager below is not running as well. There is a point I miss somewhere but where?

```
class NetworkManager {
    
    enum Endpoint {
       case searchCategory(String)
       case searhRecipes(String)
       case bookmarks(String)
       case myRefrigerator(String)
       case ingredientsAutoSearch(String)
       case getSimilarRecipes(String)
       var url: String {
                switch self {
                case .searchCategory(let category):
                    return "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?instructionsRequired=true&fillIngredients=false&addRecipeInformation=true&&sortDirection=asc&offset=0&number=10&limitLicense=false&ranking=2&type=\(category)&apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                    
                case .searhRecipes(let query):
                    return "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?instructionsRequired=true&fillIngredients=false&addRecipeInformation=true&&sortDirection=asc&offset=0&number=10&limitLicense=false&ranking=2&query=\(query)&apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                    
                case .bookmarks(let recipeID):
                    return "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/\(recipeID)/information?apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                    
                case .myRefrigerator(let ingredients):
                    return
                "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients=\(ingredients)&number=10&apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                    
                case .ingredientsAutoSearch(let searchItem):
                    return
                "https://api.spoonacular.com/food/ingredients/autocomplete?query=\(searchItem)&number=5&apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                    
                case .getSimilarRecipes(let recipeID):
                    return
                "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/\(recipeID)/similar?apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                }
            }
    }
    
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    
    
    
    private init() {}
    
    typealias IngredientsCompletion = (Result<[Ingredient], SPError>) -> Void
    typealias FindByIngredientsCompletion = (Result<[FindByIngredients], SPError>) -> Void
    typealias GetSimilarRecipesCompletion = (Result<[GetSimilarRecipes], SPError>) -> Void

    
    func getRecipesInfo(for endpoint: Endpoint, completed: @escaping (Result<[Recipe], SPError>) -> Void, ingredientsCompleted: IngredientsCompletion? = nil, findByIngCompleted: FindByIngredientsCompletion? = nil, getSimilarCompleted: GetSimilarRecipesCompletion? = nil) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint.url) else {
            completed(.failure(.invalidQuery))
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let _ = error {
                completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completed(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                switch endpoint {
                case .searchCategory(_):
                    let recipes = try decoder.decode(RecipeResults.self, from: data)
                    completed(.success(recipes.results))
                    
                case .searhRecipes(_):
                    let recipes = try decoder.decode(RecipeResults.self, from: data)
                    completed(.success(recipes.results))
                    
                case .bookmarks(_):
                    let recipes = try decoder.decode(Recipe.self, from: data)
                    completed(.success([recipes]))
                    
                case .myRefrigerator(_):
                    guard let findByIngCompleted = findByIngCompleted else { fatalError("findByIngCompleted closure must be provided for .myRefrigerator case") }
                    let recipes = try decoder.decode([FindByIngredients].self, from: data)
                    findByIngCompleted(.success(recipes))
        
                case .ingredientsAutoSearch(_):
                    guard let ingredientsCompleted = ingredientsCompleted else { fatalError("ingredientsCompleted closure must be provided for .ingredientsAutoSearch case") }
                    let ingredients = try decoder.decode([Ingredient].self, from: data)
                    ingredientsCompleted(.success(ingredients))
                    
                case .getSimilarRecipes(_):
                    guard let getSimilarCompleted = getSimilarCompleted else { fatalError("getSimilarCompleted closure must be provided for .getSimilarRecipes case")}
                    let similarRecipes = try decoder.decode([GetSimilarRecipes].self, from: data)
                    getSimilarCompleted(.success(similarRecipes))
                }
            } catch {
                completed(.failure(.invalidData))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I tried to get the `recipeID` to be passed into that function and make the network call to get the similar recipes related to that `recipeID`. Actually when I paste the `recipeID` coming from another VC onto the browser I get the result and I also I can get it on this line in network manager when I put a breakpoint there:

```
 case .getSimilarRecipes(let recipeID):
                    return
                "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/\(recipeID)/similar?apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
                }
```

but I don't get results. If needed I can provide the model I use for this and also JSON response from the browser.

---

Firstly, I have a custom `tabBarController` which holds my tabs. Inside `BookmarksVC` I get the hold of the `recipeID` here in this func and pass it to the func named `fetchSimilarRecipes` inside homeVC. Here is my custom `tabBarController`:

```
class SPTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    
    let isLoggedIn = Auth.auth().currentUser != nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .systemMint
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        viewControllers = [createHomeNC(), createRecipesNC(), createBookmarksNC(), createProfileNC()]
        
        // Trigger the function in BookmarksVC when the app starts
        if let bookmarksNavVC = viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController,
           let bookmarksVC = bookmarksNavVC.viewControllers.first as? BookmarksVC {
            bookmarksVC.fetchBookmarkedRecipeIDs()
        }
    }
    
    
    func createHomeNC() -> UINavigationController {
        let homeVC = HomeVC()
        homeVC.title = "HOME"
        homeVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(systemName: "house.fill"), tag: 0)
        
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
    }
    
 
    func createRecipesNC() -> UINavigationController  {
        let recipesVC = FridgeVC()
        recipesVC.title = "MY FRIDGE"
        recipesVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Fridge", image: UIImage(systemName: "refrigerator"), tag: 1)
        
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: recipesVC)
    }
    
    
    func createBookmarksNC() -> UINavigationController  {
        let bookmarksVC = BookmarksVC()
        bookmarksVC.title = "Bookmarks"
        bookmarksVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Bookmarks", image: UIImage(systemName: "bookmark.fill"), tag: 2)
        
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: bookmarksVC)
    }
    
    
    func createProfileNC() -> UINavigationController  {
        let viewController: UIViewController
        if isLoggedIn {
            viewController = ProfileVC()
        } else {
            viewController = AuthenticationVC()
        }
        
        viewController.title = "View Profile"
        viewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Profile", image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), tag: 3)
        
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    }
}

and here is how I get recipeID in bookmarksVC 

    guard let recipes = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }
               
                if categoryID == "Recently Viewed" {
                    if let firstRecipe = recipes.first,
                       let recipeData = firstRecipe.data() as? [String: Any],
                       let nestedDict  = recipeData.values.first as? [String: Any],
                       let recipeID = nestedDict["id"] as? Int64 {
                        print("TarifID is: \(recipeID)")
                        
                        // Create a completion handler closure
                            let completion: (Result<[GetSimilarRecipes], SPError>) -> Void = { result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let similarRecipes):
                                    print("Fetched similar recipes: \(similarRecipes)")
                                case .failure(let error):
                                    print("Error fetching similar recipes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                }
                            }
                        
                        if let homeNavVC =
                            SPTabBarController().viewControllers?[0] as? UINavigationController,
                           let homeVC = homeNavVC.viewControllers.first as? HomeVC {
                            homeVC.fetchSimilarRecipes(recipeID: String(recipeID), completion: completion)
                            //fetchSimilarRecipesClosure?(recipeID)
                        }

here is my new network call

    func getSimilarRecipes(recipeID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[GetSimilarRecipes], SPError>) -> Void) {
        
        let urlString = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/\(recipeID)/similar?apiKey=\(Api.apiKey)"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidQuery))
            return
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            if let _ = error {
                completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(.invalidData))
                return
            }

            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let similarRecipes = try decoder.decode([GetSimilarRecipes].self, from: data)
                completion(.success(similarRecipes))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(.invalidData))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Here is the homeVC

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {
    
    var user: User?
    let titleLabel                      = SPTitleLabel(textAlignment: .left, fontSize: 20)
    let userImage                       = SPImageView(cornerRadius: 40)
    let querySearchBar                  = SPSearchBar()
    var queryRecipesVC: QueryRecipesVC!
    let cancelButton                    = SPButton(backgroundColor: .clear, title: "Cancel")
    var recipes: [(tag: String, recipe: [Recipe])]      = []
    var similarRecipesArray: [GetSimilarRecipes] = []
    let categoryHeaderView              = CategoriesHeaderView()
    let recommendationHeaderTitle       = SPTitleLabel(text: "Recommendation", textAlignment: .left, fontSize: 20)
    
    let recommendationSeeAllButton      = SPButton(backgroundColor: .clear, title: "See All")
    let tags = [Tags.breakfast, Tags.lunch, Tags.dinner, Tags.soup, Tags.dessert]
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    private var searchDebounceTimer: Timer?
    
    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CategoriesCollectionViewCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.register(RecommendationCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: RecommendationCollectionViewCell.reuseID)
        collectionView.register(CategoriesHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "CategoriesHeader", withReuseIdentifier: CategoriesHeaderView.headerIdentifier)
        collectionView.register(RecommendationHeaderView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: "RecommendationHeader", withReuseIdentifier: RecommendationHeaderView.headerIdentifier)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
       
        return collectionView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        configureCompositionalLayout()
        setupQueryRecipesVC()
        layoutUI()
        fetchRecipeData()
        configure()
        createDismissKeyboardTapGesture()
        retrieveUserInfo()
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    private func setupQueryRecipesVC() {
        queryRecipesVC = QueryRecipesVC()
        addChild(queryRecipesVC)
        view.addSubview(queryRecipesVC.view)
        queryRecipesVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        queryRecipesVC.view.isHidden = true
        queryRecipesVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        querySearchBar.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    @objc func cancelButtonTapped() {
        queryRecipesVC.view.isHidden = true
        collectionView.isHidden = false
        cancelButton.isHidden = true
        querySearchBar.text = ""
    }

    
    func retrieveUserInfo() {
        PersistenceManager.retrieveUserProfile { [weak self] result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let user):
                            print("USER IS: \(user)")
                            if let profileImageUrl = user?.profileImageUrl,
                               let name = user?.name {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self?.userImage.downloadImage(fromURL: profileImageUrl)
                                    self?.titleLabel.text = "What would you like to cook today, \(name)?"
                                        print("PROFILE IMAGE URL IS: \(profileImageUrl)")
                                }
                                
                            }
        
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Error retrieving user profile: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }
                }
    
    
    func getCategories(tag: String, atIndex index: Int, group: DispatchGroup) {
        NetworkManager.shared.getRecipesInfo(for: .searchCategory(tag)) { [weak self] category in
            
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            switch category {
            case .success(let categories):
                self.updateUI(with: categories, atIndex: index)
            case .failure(let error):
                break
            }
            group.leave()
        }
    }
    
    func fetchRecipeData() {
        recipes = tags.map { (tag: $0, recipe: []) }
        
        for (index, tag) in tags.enumerated() {
            group.enter()
            getCategories(tag: tag, atIndex: index, group: group)
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func configure() {
        collectionView.setUp(to: view, and: querySearchBar)
        cancelButton.isHidden = true
    }
    
    
    func updateUI(with categories: [Recipe], atIndex index: Int) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.recipes[index].recipe = categories
        }
    }
    
    
    func fetchSimilarRecipes(recipeID: String, completion: @escaping (Result<[GetSimilarRecipes], SPError>) -> Void) {
        print("Fetching similar recipes for recipeID: \(recipeID)")
        NetworkManager.shared.getSimilarRecipes(recipeID: recipeID) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let similarRecipes):
                print("Fetched similar recipes: \(similarRecipes)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(similarRecipes))
                    self.similarRecipesArray = similarRecipes
                    print("SIMILAR RECIPES ARE: \(self.similarRecipesArray)")
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching similar recipes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.tableView)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func createDismissKeyboardTapGesture() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

Comment: Ensure, your async functions have _one_ and _only one_ completion handler. Also, ensure your completion handler _will be eventually_ and _asynchronously_ called. Best practice is also, that the completion handler will always be dispatched on the _same_ dispatch queue/execution context, no matter which path in your code will call the completion handler.

Comment: so do you mean I should separate this endpoint in a different function? But other endpoints working fine . I had 5 endpoints till this one and all works fine. why this not?

Comment: An async function (specifically your `getRecipesInfo(...) `) should eventually return a result _once_ and _only once_. You can't have more than one completion handler. To be more clear, as it is now, it might only give you the illusion that it works in "some cases".  I fear, you need to rethink your design. Start with analysing the problem. Note, you can use an enum to represent unrelated results - even though, I would not choose such a solution.

Comment: in this specific case getRecipesInfo is used in the same vc which is HomeVc and it tries to fetch data from both .searchCategory and .getSimilarRecipes ? is that why?

Comment: It's probably better to define a specific async function ("calling a service") for each input type and related output. That is, you will have more async functions, each having their specific input and returning their specific output. You also should name this functions accordingly. So, your view controller may have code to handle all these cases. What these service functions do actually, say, calling a network endpoint, or calling CoreData, is an _implementation detail_ of these service functions.

Comment: i am adding my homeVC to give an idea. I separated the function for new network call and it still doesn't working, I ll clarify in a new response in detail